# how to add dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

[I want to make a dropdown clickable button which should open like this on small browser size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft0lQ.png)

[And should be seen like this on large and medium browser size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chV4i.png)

Though my items are visible in large and medium browser size but i am unable to put those items in the drop down button. On clicking that button no action is taking place.
Here is the code of my web page... Please someone fix this problem

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>DEV RESTAURANT</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="restaurant.css"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo:ital,wght@0,900;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar navbar-light ">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="restaurant.html">
            <img id="logo-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Burger_King_logo_%281999%29.svg/640px-Burger_King_logo_%281999%29.svg.png" alt="burger king">
          </a>
          <a id="brand-name" href="restaurant.html">Burger King</a>
          </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="navbar" id="navbarNav">
            <ul id="nav-list" class="navbar">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="menu-categories.html"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i><br>Menu</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="menu-categories.html"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><br>About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="menu-categories.html"><i class="fas fa-award"></i><br>Awards</a>
              </li>
              <li id="phone" class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="tel: 222-222-222"><span>222-222-222</span></a><div>*We deliver</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          

        </div>
      </nav>
   
    </header> 

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>





body {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #61122f;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}
#header-nav {
    background-color: gold;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#logo-img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px 15px 10px 0px;
    margin-left: -6%;
}
#brand-name {
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #ef151e;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar#navbarNav {
    float: right ;
}
#nav-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: -5%;
}
#nav-list a {
    color: #61122f;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav-list a:hover {
    background: floralwhite;
}
#nav-list a i {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
#phone {
    margin-top: -4%;
}
#phone a { /*Phone number*/
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
#phone div { /*We deliver*/
    color: #557c3e;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.navbar-toggler {
    margin-right: 0;
}
@media(min-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px){
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
     #logo-img , #navbarNav  {
        display: none;
    }
}
```